# How to receive data with WinHttpSendRequest from localhost

Tags: c++, winapi, winhttp

I try to receive some data using GET Parameter.
When i try to get the data from a webadress it works fine.
Just i changed the webserver to localhost i will not receive the data and get ERROR 12175

What do i have to change, that my code works for web-connection AND for localhost testing?

When i type the localhost adress to my browser i wil receive the expected result.

```
LPCWSTR server = L"www.airfieldmanager-game.de";    //this works fine
//LPCWSTR server = L"localhost";    //causes Error 12175 at WinHttpSendRequest. Variables hSession, hConnect and cRequest looks fine.
LPCWSTR serverRequest = L"/php/TestCURL.php?data=1&param=Gesendete Daten!";

// Use WinHttpOpen to obtain a session handle.
hSession = WinHttpOpen(L"WinHTTP Example/1.0",
    WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
    WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,
    WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);

// Specify an HTTP server.
if (hSession)
    hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hSession, server,
    INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, 0);

// Create an HTTP request handle.
if (hConnect)
    hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, L"GET", serverRequest,
    NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,
    WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,
    WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE);

// Send a request.
if (hRequest)
    bResults = WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest,
    WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0,
    WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0,
    0, 0);


// End the request.
if (bResults)
    bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest, NULL);

if (!bResults)
{
    int i = GetLastError();    //when using loscalhost i becomes 12175
}
```

Comment: what certificat use your local server ? are it containing *localhost* ?

Comment: i think you need `WinHttpSetOption` with `WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS`  for set `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID | SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA`

Comment: I use standard installation of XAMPP for localhost. So i think there will be no certificate installed.

Now i tried to add a WinHttpSetOption directly after WinHttpOpen

     // Set Security Flags
 DWORD dwSecOption = SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID | SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA;

 int itmp = WinHttpSetOption(hSession,
  WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS,
  &dwSecOption,
  sizeof(dwSecOption));

Comment: why you in this case use `WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE` ?

Comment: Thanks, thats it! 
Removed WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE with 0 and now it works for both localhost and website. 
Thanks a lot. 
How can i mark your answer as solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

error `12175` this is `ERROR_WINHTTP_SECURE_FAILURE`. the [`WinHttpSendRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpsendrequest) explain when this error happens and how get more info about it:

> One or more errors were found in the *Secure Sockets Layer (SSL)*
>   certificate sent by the server. To determine what type of error was
>   encountered, verify through a
>   [`WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_SECURE_FAILURE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winhttp/nc-winhttp-winhttp_status_callback) notification in a status
>   callback function.

so for debug diagnostic how minimum you need write self cb:

```
void CALLBACK WinHttpStatusCB(
                                      __in  HINTERNET hInternet,
                                      __in  DWORD_PTR dwContext,
                                      __in  DWORD dwInternetStatus,
                                      __in  LPVOID lpvStatusInformation,
                                      __in  DWORD dwStatusInformationLength
                                      )
{
    switch (dwInternetStatus)
    {
    case WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_SECURE_FAILURE:
        if (lpvStatusInformation && dwStatusInformationLength == sizeof(ULONG))
        {
            DbgPrint("SECURE_FAILURE:[%x]\n", *(PULONG)lpvStatusInformation);
            // ...
        }
        break;
    //...
    }
}
```

and activate it:

```
WinHttpSetStatusCallback(hSession, WinHttpStatusCB, WINHTTP_CALLBACK_FLAG_ALL_NOTIFICATIONS, 0);
```

or

```
WinHttpSetStatusCallback(hSession, WinHttpStatusCB, WINHTTP_CALLBACK_FLAG_SECURE_FAILURE, 0);
```

with this you can gor exactly reason of failure - several `WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_FLAG_*` flags.

> If the `dwInternetStatus` argument is
>   `WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_SECURE_FAILURE`, then `lpvStatusInformation`
>   points to a `DWORD` which is a bitwise-OR combination of one or more
>   of the following values. read [more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winhttp/nc-winhttp-winhttp_status_callback)

however and from general view we can understand - the CN in sertificat which use server must be the same as site dns name used in request. if you use *localhost* here - then CN name of server certificate must be also local host or you got how minimum `WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_FLAG_CERT_CN_INVALID`:

> SSL certificate common name (host name field) is incorrect, for
>   example, if you entered *localhost* and the common name on the
>   certificate says *heilpraxis-einssein.de*.

for not got such errors you can use [`WinHttpSetOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpsetoption) with [`WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinHttp/option-flags). you need think how minimum set `SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID`

> Allows an invalid common name in a certificate; that is, the server
>   name specified by the application does not match the common name in
>   the certificate. If this flag is set, the application does not receive
>   a `WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_FLAG_CERT_CN_INVALID` callback.

but can set multiple flags:

```
            ULONG flags = 
                SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA|
                SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID|
                SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID|
                SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_WRONG_USAGE;

            WinHttpSetOption(hRequest, WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, &flags, sizeof(flags));
```